# Running at close to 100 cpu

Tags: cpu, script, python

So I have a python script that is really pushing the limits on concurrency. When the script is running, the cpu load of my computer is close to 100% at all times. Can this harm my computer?

To be fair I am running the script several times at the same time as well.

Comment: CPUs are designed to be under load.  You cannot damage a CPU simply because its under 100% load unless its temperature is outside of its operating temperatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can or should?

In a properly designed system: No, it will not damage the CPU.

In the case of older CPU's with badly designed systems, lack of cooling (e.g. failed fans, coolers full of dust and working badly, ...) then yes, this might push it over the edge.  In the case of modern CPU (where modern is from the last decade) they will not get damaged but will slow down. Older CPUs (e.g. 486 chips) will heat up beyond design temperatures and either crash or have shortened lifespans.

But in anything from the last 10-15 years: No. A CPU is build to do calculations. It is not harmed by doing calculations. Your case may be relative noisy though with fans revving up to dispose of the heat but things should be just fine (if noisy).

Comment: Thanks for answering, and yes, it's very noisy...